One within the other
What letters are missing? Explain your reasoning.



Some knowledge is required ofc but I think it's too basic to add a knowledge-tag.

I think the missing letters are:

 
 (‘FE’ is Iron)

Reason

 The Cartesian grid shows the coordinates of the red circle being (1,1) and those of blue circle being (2,0). This can be converted into XY AND XX. These are the pairing of sex chromosomes for males and females respectively.


 The red and blue circles therefore represent the masculine and feminine genders respectively.


 This however entails several word pairs that could depict the genders… so which one to pick to fill in the diagram? The picture on the right shows a ‘Venn diagram’ that we must fill in a way depicting the letter strings which both of these words share and which encompasses (or just is) the entire masculine word (to be placed in the red circle) and which only the feminine word has which has to be a chemical symbol (to be placed only within in the blue). MALE/FEMALE is the only common pairing that fits. From here it is obvious how to fill the diagram to then complete the puzzle.


Good job! This is correct
